# BPOS pop3 ssl fetchmail

Tags: linux, ssl, email, bpos

Trying to configure fetchmail to pull down pop3 ssl mail from BPOS red001.mail.microsoftonline.com pop3 server. However, appears BPOS ssl certificate is self-signed, and will not allow a succesful ssl login.

Followed guide at http://bronski.net/data/fetchmail-eng.php

Anyone here able to make fetchmail pull BPOS pop3 ssl mailbox?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this issue. Answering my question incase anyone google's this and this helps 
them.

.fetchmailrc

```
# initial setup

set postmaster "localaccount"
set daemon 600
set invisible

# must provide ssl fingerprint for self signed ssl certificates
# use "fetchmail -d0 -vk red001.mail.microsoftonline.com" to find server ssl fingerprint
sslfingerprint "00:00:00:00:00:00:00:0B:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00"

# accounts to poll

#username@domain.com

poll "red001.mail.microsoftonline.com" protocol POP3 uidl auth password
user 'username@domain.com' there with password 'password' is localaccount here options ssl
#mda "/usr/bin/procmail -m /home/localaccount/.procmailrc"
keep
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've configured fetchmail with the `--sslcertck` option, as covered [in the manual](http://fetchmail.berlios.de/fetchmail-man.html#19).  Try removing that option.  If that doesn't help the information [requested in the FAQ](http://fetchmail.berlios.de/fetchmail-FAQ.html#G3) would help in diagnosing the problem, as would a review of the [fetchmail-users mailing list archive](http://lists.berlios.de/pipermail/fetchmail-users/) where this type of problem comes up fairly regularly (a few times a year anyway).

I'd also note that the guide you refer to covers a **very** old version of fetchmail, as such it's probably no longer entirely accurate.